# PHP - Expose own size to client (so the client knows how much it is downloading)

Tags: php, sql, delphi, dynamic, size

My PHP script is outputting the contents of a .sql file, after it has been called by a POST request from my Delphi Desktop Client.

Here is what is happening:

1. My Desktop Client sends a POST request to my PHP Script.
2. The Script then calls `mysqldump` and generates a file - `xdb_backup.sql`
3. The Script then `include "xdb_backup.sql";` which will print and return it to the Desktop Client, whereafter it deletes the SQL file.

The problem is, that the size of the SQL file can vary (for testing, I generated one that is 6 mb). I would like my desktop client to be able to show the progress, however the PHP script does not expose it's size, so I have no `Progressbar.Max` value to assign.

How can I make my PHP script let the Client know how big it is `before the whole thing is over` ?

Note: Downloading the SQL file is not an option, as the script has to destroy it. :)

Comment: The only way I can see doing this is making a rough approximation based on how many data fields there are and how big they tend to be. But very interesting q +1

Comment: @Obto Thank you for the +1 :) - Turns out the answer was simple though. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would do

```
$fsize = filesize($file_path);
```

where $file_path will be path to the generated file xdb_backup.sql,

to get the filesize in server and return headers with the following line attached.

```
header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);
```

Take a look at http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/php/47774-download-script-not-sending-file-size-header-corrupt-files-since-using-remote-file-server.html which explains a download php script.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send a Content-Length header using `header` function. Something like this:

`header('Content-Length: '.filesize('yourfile.sql'));`

You may want to send the file using `readfile` instead of include.

Comment: So will the client know the size before it starts processing the sql file?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Content-Length header with the size of xdb_backup.sql